# Explicit solution for a non-linear recurrence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Does the following non-linear recurrence equation has an explicit solution with given boundary conditions $x_0$ and $x_\infty$?
$$ x_n = a + b x_{n-1}x_{n+1} $$
$a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: Remarks: Is $L=x_{\infty}$ finite ? In this case, its 2 possible values are known because $L$ is necessarily solution to the quadratic equation $L=a+bL^2$. Another thing: are you sure you dont need also to give $x_1$ ?

Comment: Yes, $L$ is finite and as you mentioned it has at most two possible values.

Comment: You have not answered concerning the fact that $a_1$ should as well be given. If $a_1$ is chosen at our own will, how can you await a unique general explicit solution ?

Comment: No, $x_1$ is not given. But if an explicit solution is found in terms of $x_0$ and $x_1$ then it may be useful too.